# Finding the top three relevant category and its corresponding probabilities

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

From the below script, I find the highest probability and its corresponding category in a multi class text classification problem. How do I find the highest top 3 predicted probability and its corresponding category in a best efficient way without using loops.

```
probabilities = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)
max_probabilities = probabilities.max(axis=1)
order=np.argsort(probabilities, axis=1)
classification=(classifier.classes_[order[:, -1:]])
print(accuracy_score(classification,y_test))
```

Thanks in advance.
( I have around 50 categories, I want to extract the top 3 best relevant category among 50 categories for each of my narrations and display them in a dataframe)

Comment: Assuming that `classifier.classes_` is a `numpy` using array `order[:, -3:] ` will give you the top three classes.

Comment: Thanks. Can I know how do i find the corresponding probabilities of the 3 predicted classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done most of the hard work here, just missing a bit of `numpy` foo to finish it off. Your line

```
order = np.argsort(probabilities, axis=1)
```

Contains the indices of the sorted probabilities, so `[[lowest_prob_class_1, ..., highest_prob_class_1]...]` for each of your samples. Which you have used to give your classification with `order[:, -1:]`, i.e. the index of the highest probability class. So to get the top three classes we can just make a simple change

```
top_3_classes = classifier.classes_[order[:, -3:]]
```

Then to get the corresponding probabilities we can use

```
top_3_probabilities = probabilities[np.repeat(np.arange(order.shape[0]), 3),
                                    order[:, -3:].flatten()].reshape(order.shape[0], 3)
```

Comment: Thanks its easy to retrieve the top 3 classes but, probabilities[order[:, -3:]] doesn't give the corresponding probabilities

Comment: Ah you're correct! A lesson in checking my code before I submit it. I've updated my code so that it works for the probabilities now.